# azure mobile service .net backend not working after nuget packages update

Tags: azure-mobile-services

After updating the nu-get packages for a previously working Azure Mobile Service (.Net back-end), I now get the following error when accessing Table Controllers:

```
An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.",
"exceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException",
"stackTrace":"at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Serialization. 
SelectExpandWrapperConverter.ODataReflectedTypes..ctor() 
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Serialization ...
```

Custom Controllers appear to be unaffected.

I've probably missed something obvious, but I can't see it

Any help would be appreciated

Many Thanks

K.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Henrik F. Nielsen's [answer in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/2f56f9b6-311f-4d96-aa2c-9da53639256a):

> There are known incompatibilities with the latest version of ASP.NET Web API which was released the same day as our last update. We are working on an update but in the mean time please don't update all your NuGets but *only* the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.* packages -- they will then include the right dependencies the need.

This is an integration issue with the .NET backend binaries, and it should be resolved soon.

Comment: You can now update the Azure Mobile Service NuGets to version 405 which supports ASP.NET Web API.

When you update then be careful *ONLY* to update the Mobile Service nugets -- they will pull in the other dependencies they need. Do not hit "Update All" as not all other packages are compatible.

Thanks,

Henrik

Comment: Did you also update WindowsAzure.ServiceBus? The OWIN packages? I can't wait until NuGet 3.0 sorts out this mess.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @carlosfigueira's answer, it seems that the WepApi 5.2.0 version is not compatible with Azure Mobile Services yet.

I am one of the unfortunate ones who decided to let nuget go to town and update all the packages in the project so here is what I did to deal with this.

Uninstall every nuget package from your mobile service project.  Then add them back.  Start by using only the Microsoft Azure Mobile Services.NET Backend.* packages - This will pull the currently compatible WebApi 5.1.2 instead of 5.2.0. and other dependent assemblies.

In addition, I was getting a lot of weird redirect binding errors which I believe the tooling added incorrectly - so I commented out all the dependentAssembly tags in the assemblyBindings and then added them back as the mobile service complained.  All I had to add back for redirects were Newtonsoft.Json and Microsoft.Owin.  YMMV.

I think this may also have something to do with the fact that there are strange interactions between VS and source control plugins since nuget packages sometimes fail because they can't obtain write permissions for packages.config and web.config files.

I am also using a PCL in my service which requires adding the Microsoft.Bcl libraries - perhaps irrelevant but it is what lead me to discovering the underlying error.

Under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run, set the MSBuild project build output verbosity to Detailed or above to get some insight into what is happening in the process.

**[Update 12/24/2014]**

I updated something I shouldn't have and everything broke again.

Uninstall all nuget packages.  Delete all dependentAssembly elements from the Web.Config file.  Save and restart Visual Studio.

Start adding packages back using the following from the Package Manager Console.  In my case:

- Install-Package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend -Version 1.0.405
- Install-Package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables -Version 1.0.405
- Install-Package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity -Version 1.0.405
- Install-Package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.SignalR -Version 1.0.405
- Install-Package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Storage -Version 1.0.405

Never touch it again...?